# Connecting to multiple databases with sqlsrv_connect

Tags: php, sql-server, php-5.3

Can anyone help me or provide advice on this connection issue I am having. Basically at the moment I can connect to one database at a time. The thing is the data that I am querying is from multiple website (all starting with V1_database.....). For example my database include V1_database_newyork or V1_database_denver etc.

I have created a query like this in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio which picks up all the database beginning with V1_database:

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb') AND name LIKE 'V1_database%'
```

My current code to connect to one of my databases is as follows (this works fine):

```
       <?php
        /*data base connection */

        $serverName = ".\SQLEXPRESS";
        $connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"V1_database_newyork",
         "UID"=>"username",
         "PWD" => "password");

        /* Connect using Windows Authentication */       
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);

        /* Check whether connnection is established */
        if($conn === false)
        {
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }


/* Close the connection. */
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
?>
```

Can anyone help me adapt this query so the connection string will allow me to query any database with "V1_database%"?

If any of this is at all unclear, please let me know! Any advice will be much appreciated!

Cheers,

Neil

Answer (score 0):

Set up a connection to multiple databases, as you would normally connect to one, then you can name them in your queries.

```
$serverName = DB_MSSQL_SERVER; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>DB_MSSQL_NAME_1, "UID"=>DB_MSSQL_USER, "PWD"=>DB_MSSQL_PASSWORD);
$this->ms_sql = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>DB_MSSQL_NAME_2, "UID"=>DB_MSSQL_USER, "PWD"=>DB_MSSQL_PASSWORD);
$this->ms_sql = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

IE SELECT column_name(s)
FROM database1.table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON database2.table1.column_name = table2.column_name;

Answer (score -1):

According to the [PHP documentation on mssql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php):

```
resource mssql_connect ([ string $servername [, string $username [, string $password [, bool $new_link ]]]] )
```

The return resource must be used in all queries, so connect to MSSQL with this:

```
$res = mssql_connect ([ string $servername [, string $username [, string $password [, bool $new_link ]]]] )
```

and use `$res` in all queries.

```
mssql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier [, int $batch_size = 0 ]] )
```

If you need connections to two database, then use `$res1` and `$res2`.
A good practice is to make some light class to store not only the connection resource, but other things, like last error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply softm. I'm not completely sure if this will work in my situation. Basically each database has data on a single track inspection run. I have quite a few of these database (i.e. multiple runs). One of my pages on my site, I need to output some basic information about each database... e.g. division and start and end mile of the run. What do you think would be the best way of doing this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated! thanks Neil

Comment: I have this situation in past, my own connectivity class not use resource links inside query's. So all query;s was done against last connected database.

So - when i init 2 databases in app init code, i have connected both class/vars to different databases ... but actually they query the last one connected.